# my javascript library cant work on all Document Elements (Before and After Calling js library problem)

Tags: javascript, html, css

i create a javascript librarys and in this library i set a Css for all span tags in document and i loaded my library in header a document and try call library in body with an script tag
and this (library) BoldFunction just work for  elements of before script tag in body and cant work for after this
i try set defer attr in loaded script of library and got ERORR your function not define because library loade after DOM and i get Erorr but i cant solve my problem

**html Codes**

```html
 <head>
  <script  src="libraryinJS.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="">test</div>
<div class="">test</div>
<div class="fss">test</div>
<div>test</div>
<div id="bld">test</div>
<span class="bld">span tag Class=bld before</span>
<div >test</div>
<script >
bold.makeboldanimate('.bld');
</script>
<span class="bld">span tag Class=bld after</span>
</body>
```

**JavaScript Codes**

```
 (function (window) {
    function Testlibrary_instance() {
        this.version = '1.0';
         this.makeboldanimate = function (cs) {
            var elements = document.querySelectorAll(cs);
            for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
                console.log(elements.length);
                elements[i].style.fontWeight = "bold";
            }
        };
        this.makespanboldanimate =  function () {
            this.makeboldanimate('span');

        };
    } 

    if (typeof (bold) === 'undefined') {
        window.bold= new Testlibrary_instance();
    } else {
        console.error('LIBRARY ERROR : Name of \"testlibrary\" already defined with type of ' + typeof testlibrary + ' in your library ');
    }
   
}(window));
```

[ّFist result in chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05ixM.png)

[The second result in chrome when i add defer attr to script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4k6bM.png)

Finally and briefly
**i want my script bold function work in all lines of html document before and after calling library in a script**

Answer (score 0):

When you write a  tag and then have more HTML after that, it wont work for HTML elements written after that.

Remember to place your  after all lines of HTML code to make it work for the whole page

Comment: ok i know this, but i want set a method with anyway that any people add script tag in above her document (html) page this code work well for all dom in page before or after calling my library

Comment: I don't see any other option that calling the function (bold.makeboldanimate('.bld')) again after writing your HTML. Can you explain why <script> tag cannot go to the end of the page?

Comment: bro i call my function between my html tags and function work for above tags and cant work for bottom tags with this class or tag and i want a method to get my Purpose and any people call my library in anywhere of her body tags or example div p a tags this library work well for all DOM or elements in document

Comment: Sorry buddy. I dont have an answer for you anymore other than calling the function again after writing your new HTML.